# Clipping a point cloud into a circular one with a defined radius

Tags: r, circle

I am trying to crop a pointcloud into a circle with a radius of 15m.

I tried `subplot = clip_circle(ctg,x,y,radius)`, but didn't work.

How can I can clip it easily in R?

Comment: which `library` did you get that `clip_circle` function from?

Comment: I used lidR along with raster and sp